# Do I need to unsubscribe from a subject if I only use it inside a component?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home2',
  templateUrl: './home2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home2.component.scss']
})
export class Home2Component implements OnInit {

  randNumberSub: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(
    Math.random()
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.randNumberSub.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(`Sample1Component ==> RandomNumber: ${data}`);
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    this.randNumberSub.next(100);
  }

}
```

I know that if I used a subject, for example, from a service that I injected, I would need to unsubscribe from it to avoid a memory leak, but if I use the subject only inside a component, will it unsubscribe when destroyed?

Comment: You do not need to unsubscribe from `randNumberSub`,  because it is a component-scoped observable, this behavior is part of Angular's built-in cleanup process. When the component is destroyed, Angular automatically unsubscribes from any subscriptions that were created within the component,

Comment: @MeerArtefakt Please make this as an answer

Comment: @MeerArtefakt - can you point to an official documentation / piece of code on Angular git repo? I don't believe that's the actual case, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @MeerArtefakt This is not true. Angular has no such specifc abilities. This needs to be explicitly unsubscribed

Comment: Always unsubscribe!

Comment: I am sorry, I mixed something up, you basically have to destroy all subscriptions yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every observable that doesn't complete needs to be explicitly unsubscribed.

In v16, Angular introduced the `takeUntilDestroyed` operator that unsubscribes when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're Angular 16+ you can just use signals, and not worry about subscriptions.  They work very similarly to BehaviorSubject, so you should have no issue converting.

```
export class Home2Component {

  randNumber = signal(Math.random());

  constructor() {
    effect(() => console.log(`Sample1Component ==> RandomNumber: ${randNumber()}`));
  }

  onClick() {
    randNumber.set(Math.random())
  }
}
```

Notice the **subscription** that was in *ngOnInit* was moved to an **effect** in the *constructor*.  Effects have to be created in the constructor or assigned to a class variable, unless the *Injector* is provided and passed as a parameter when creating the effect.